# Averaging values and getting standard devs from database to build graph

Tags: sql, go

Tricky to Explain so Ill shrink down the info to a minimum:

But first, I'll try and explain my ultimate goal, I want to take users who trialed a product and determine how that product affected a value as a percentage compared to their average baseline and then average all these percentages with stand devs.

I have database with the a table that has a user_id, a value, a date.

| user_id | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| int | int | int in epoch miliseconds |

I then have a second table which indicates when a trial began and ends for a user and the product they are using for said trial.

| user_id | start_date | end_date | product id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| int | int in epoch milisecs | int in epoch milisecs | int |

What I want to do is gather all the user's trials for one product type, and for each user that participated get a baseline value and their percent change each day. Then take all these percentages and average them and get a standard deviation for each day.

1. One problem is date needs to convert to days since start_date so anything between the start date and the first 24 hrs will be lumped as day 0, next 24 as day 1, and so forth. So ill be averaging the percents of each day
2. Not every day was recorded for each user so some will have multiple missing days, so I cant need to mark each day as days from start
3. The start_date's are random between users

So the graph will look like this:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMbLh.png)

I would prefer to do as much of it in sql as possible, but the rest will be in Golang.

I was thinking about grabbing each trial , and then each trial will have an array of results. so then I iterate over each trial and iteriate over the results for each trial picking day 0, day 1, day 2 and saving these in their own arrays which I will then average. Everything start getting super messy though

such as in semi pseudo code:

```
 db.Query("select user_id, start_date from trials where product_id = $1", productId).Scan(&trial.UserId, &trial.StartDate)

//extract trials from rows

for _, trial := range trials {
    // extract leadingAvgStart from StartDate
  db.QueryRow("select AVG(value) from results where user_id = $1 date between $2 and $3", trial.UserId, leadingAvgStart, trial.StartDate)
    // Now we have the baseline for the user

  rows :=  db.Query("select value, date from results where product_id = $1", start)
   //Now we extract the results and have and array
   //Convert Dates to Dates from start Date
   //...? It just start getting ugly and I believe there has to be a better way
}
```

How can I do most of the heavy lifting with sql?

```sql
create table users (id int PRIMARY KEY, name text);
create table products (id int PRIMARY KEY, name text);

create table values (
      id int PRIMARY KEY
    , user_id int REFERENCES users(id)
    , value int
    , date numeric
);

create table trials (
      id int PRIMARY KEY
    , user_id int REFERENCES users(id)
    , start_date numeric
    , end_date numeric
    , product_id int REFERENCES products(id)
);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO users (id, name ) VALUES
(1,'John'),
(2,'Jane'),
(3,'Billy'),
(4,'Miranda');

INSERT INTO products (id, name ) VALUES
(1, 'pill A'),
(2, 'pill B'),
(3, 'pill C'),
(4, 'exercise bal'),
(5, 'diet plan');

INSERT INTO trials (id,user_id,start_date,end_date,product_id) VALUES
(1, 1, 1667896408000, 1668099442000, 1),
(2, 1, 1667896408000, 1668099442000, 2),
(3, 2, 1667576960000, 1668074401000, 3),
(4, 3, 1667896408000, 1668099442000, 1);


INSERT INTO values (id, user_id, value, date) VALUES
(38, 1, 7, 1668182428000),
(1, 1, 7, 1668099442000),
(2, 1, 8, 1668074401000),
(3, 1, 8, 1668012300000),
(4, 1, 6, 1668011197000),
(5, 1, 6, 1667978268000),
(6, 1, 9, 1667925002000),
(7, 1, 9, 1667896408000),
(8, 1, 4, 1667838601000),
(9, 1, 6, 1667803049000),
(10, 1, 7, 1667576960000),
(12, 1, 5, 1667546428000),
(13, 1, 8, 1667490149000),
(14, 2, 8, 1668182428000),
(15, 2, 7, 1668099442000),
(16, 2, 8, 1668074401000),
(17, 2, 9, 1668012300000),
(18, 2, 6, 1668011197000),
(19, 2, 6, 1667978268000),
(20, 2, 5, 1667925002000),
(21, 2, 9, 1667896408000),
(22, 2, 4, 1667803049000),
(23, 2, 4, 1667576960000),
(24, 2, 5, 1667546428000),
(25, 2, 9, 1667490149000),
(26, 3, 6, 1668182428000),
(27, 3, 7, 1668099442000),
(28, 3, 8, 1668074401000),
(29, 3, 9, 1668011197000),
(30, 3, 6, 1667978268000),
(31, 3, 9, 1667925002000),
(32, 3, 9, 1667896408000),
(33, 3, 8, 1667838601000),
(34, 3, 6, 1667803049000),
(35, 3, 4, 1667576960000),
(36, 3, 5, 1667546428000),
(37, 3, 6, 1667490149000);
```

Comment: I would be surprised if you cannot do all of this in SQL; however it's likely that some product specific functions will be needed (date functions [vary considerably](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-date-and-time-functions/)) so please let us know what you are using (Postgres, MySQL, MSSQL etc).  It would also be easier to answer with sample data and the result you expect from that data; consider using something like [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to provide sample data.

Comment: create table users (id int PRIMARY KEY);
create table products (id int PRIMARY KEY, product int);
create table values (id int PRIMARY KEY, user_id int REFERENCES users(id), value int, date int);
create table trials (id int PRIMARY KEY, user_id int REFERENCES users(id), start_date int, end_date int, product_id int REFERENCES products(id));

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with stackoverflow super well yet. Anyways it is in Postgres, above creates the tables I used in sqlfiddle. So as an observer we have all of these users who use different products and record a value daily (sometimes they forget to record). We want visually see how the users are affected by an individual product on average over time and the standard deviation. So we may have 20 products and hundreds of users who use different products at different times (Trials).

Comment: The actual / specific calculations are not clear.  It would help if you provide at least a minimal amount of data, and the exact expected result based on that data, along with the mathematical calculation used to produce that result.  The result must be derivable from the test data.

Comment: The concept of "days since start" is clear.  It's the rest of the logic that's unclear.  If your question is about performing some general calculation based on "days_since_start", and you don't really care, for this question, about which general calculation is performed, then reduce the problem to something trivial, like: "Find the average {value} per day(x), over all data", where day(x) is just the "days since start" relative to each trial start.

Comment: Jon thanks for your replies, I was off this project for a bit and now back to it. I updated the sql calls above to reflect the database and some data.

Comment: So basically lets say there is a study being done on sleep with different drugs or other common solutions. these users monitor there sleep eveyday except they forget some days. We are storing the exact milisecond when they wake up and record their hours of sleep. They all have some average baseline before they started a trial. So if we have a few people trialing pill A I want to see everyone average for day 1, day 2, day 3 etc

Comment: So over the course of year a thousand people may trial pilll A, all at different times and I want to see how pill A effects sleep day 1, day 2, day 3 etc. So I take eveyone's day 0 and get the average and standard deviation, then day 2... etc...

Comment: That's fine.  Please add the mathematical equations / calculations to be performed.  If the particular calculation isn't important, just dream up some simple calculation to be calculated "per day of trial" as an example.  The calculation should refer to the schema in the question... and the expected result should be based on the data provided in the question.

Comment: Hmm so if I was to wrtie it in psuedo code it would be something like

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figures it out, basically I do two inner join queries and treat those as tables and then inner join those, and use a group by to average

```
select 
  query1.product_uuid, 
  query1.days, 
  AVG(query1.value / query2.avg) as avg_percent 
from 
  (
    select 
      DATE_PART(
        'day', 
        to_timestamp(
          values 
            .date / 1000
        ):: date - trials.start_date
      ) as days, 
      trials.uuid as trial_uuid, 
      trials.product_uuid, 
    values 
      .value as value 
    from 
    values 
      as 
    values 
      inner join product_trials as trials ON 
    values 
      .user_id = trials.user_id 
    where 
    values 
      .source = 'Trued' 
      and 
    values 
      .use = 'true' 
      AND trials.start_date IS NOT NULL 
      AND trials.end_date IS NOT NULL 
      AND to_timestamp(
        values 
          .date / 1000
      ):: date > trials.start_date 
      AND to_timestamp(
        values 
          .date / 1000
      ):: date < trials.end_date
  ) as query1 
  inner join (
    select 
    values 
      .user_id, 
      trials.uuid as trial_uuid, 
      AVG(value) 
    from 
    values 
      inner join product_trials as trials ON 
    values 
      .user_id = trials.user_id 
    where 
      source = 'Trued' 
      and use = true 
      AND trials.start_date IS NOT NULL 
      AND trials.end_date IS NOT NULL 
      AND to_timestamp(
        values 
          .date / 1000
      ):: date < trials.start_date 
      AND DATE_PART(
        'day', 
        to_timestamp(
          values 
            .date / 1000
        ):: date - trials.start_date
      ) > -20 
    GROUP BY 
    values 
      .user_id, 
      trials.uuid
  ) as query2 ON query1.trial_uuid = query2.trial_uuid 
where 
  query2.avg > 0 
GROUP BY 
  query1.days, 
  query1.product_uuid 
ORDER BY 
  query1.product_uuid, 
  query1.days
```